# Error while reading PNG image dimensions

Tags: java

I am trying to read the dimensions of a PNG image, but I encounter the below error while doing so -

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readHeader(PNGImageReader.java:307)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:637)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1212)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1560)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
```

Here is the code I have that's causing it -

```
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myImgByteArray);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    System.out.println("Height: " +image.getHeight()+ "Width: " +image.getWidth());
```

Can someone please suggest what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're feeding `ImageIO` with valid PNG data? Did you try opening the file in some imaging software and letting `ImageIO` read it directly instead of providing a stream?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well. I tried reading the file by writing the image to an output stream. The image shows up correctly. Only see the problem when reading the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You may user the other way to get the image dimensions:

```
BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File(imageFilePath));
System.out.println(image.getHeight());
System.out.println(image.getWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you constructing `myImgByteArray`. Try this one.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream((new File("resources/1.png"))));
System.out.println("Height: " + image.getHeight() + "Width: " + image.getWidth());
```

---

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from absolute path
ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is something wrong when u load the image in the BuggeredImage. He is my test code.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
       try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/adrian/Documents/wave.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Height: " +image.getHeight()+ " Width: " +image.getWidth());
```

This is the output:

```
Height: 1170 Width: 2576
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Show us how u get the myImgByteArray so we can see if there is an error before.

Comment: `BuggeredImage` - lol, was this on purpose? ^_^ (if there's something wrong when loading the image, it is indeed buggered)

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
public LoadImageApp() {
   try {
       img = ImageIO.read(new File("/workspace/ImageProject/src/myPic.png"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (img == null) {
         return new Dimension(100,100);
    } else {
       System.out.println("Height: " +img.getHeight()+ " Width: " +img.getWidth());        
       return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
   }
}
```

Make sure you are calling the file location correctly! In Linux your path has to be in this format :
`/path/to/my/file.png` 
while in Windows, this is the path to the file:
`C:\\workspace\\path\to\myFile.png`

Comment: Please read the example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java